# How to dynamically update absolute path

Tags: java, string, absolute-path

Given the below incoming path, e.g.

```
C:\cresttest\parent_3\child_3_1\child_3_1_.txt
```

How can one update and add new dir in between above path to construct below result

```
C:\cresttest\NEW_PATH\parent_3\child_3_1\child_3_1_.txt
```

Currently I am using multiple subString to identify the incoming path, but incoming path are random and dynamic. Using substring and placing my new path requires more line of code or unnecessary processing, is there any API or way to easily update and add my new dir in between the absolute path?

Comment: To help you here we need to knowwhat's the criteria to insert a new folder... Is the `C:\cresttest\` part fix? or can that one change too?

Comment: You should probably have a look at using the [java.nio.file.Path class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), especially it's `subpath` method.

Comment: @ParkerHalo C:\cresttest part is not fixed, this is dynamic and could be anything. I have to add my new path just after the first dir. then keep the remaining path as is.

Comment: so, if any part is fixed... can you at least give a pattern of desired changing behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

By using [java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html), you could to the following:

```
Path incomingPath = Paths.get("C:\\cresttest\\parent_3\\child_3_1\\child_3_1_.txt");
//getting C:\cresttest\, adding NEW_PATH to it
Path subPathWithAddition = incomingPath.subpath(0, 2).resolve("NEW_PATH");
//Concatenating C:\cresttest\NEW_PATH\ with \parent_3\child_3_1\child_3_1_.txt
Path finalPath = subPathWithAddition.resolve(incomingPath.subpath(2, incomingPath.getNameCount()));
```

You could then get the path URI by calling `finalPath.toUri()`

Note: this doesn't depend on any names in your path, it depends on the directory depth though, which you could edit in the `subpath` calls.

Note 2: you could probably reduce the amount of `Path` instances you make to one, I made three to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, I ran and got output as cresttest\parent_3\NEW_PATH\child_3_1\child_3_1_.txt. Is it possible to get the c:\\ as well along with the result

Comment: What about `finalPath.toAbsolutePath().toURI()`? If that doesn't work, you could append "C:\" yourself (a bit dirty, but if it works for your use case it's okay I guess)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply insert a path at the second backslash like this:

```
String path="C:\\cresttest\\parent_3\\child_3_1\\child_3_1_.txt";

final String slash="\\\\";
path=path.replaceFirst(slash+"[^"+slash+"]+"+slash, "$0NEW_PATH"+slash);

System.out.println(path);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Q34EaM)

This replaces the first occurrence of `\\arbitrarydirname\\` with itself (referred to via `$0`) followed by `NEWPATH\\`.

The separator’s source code representation looks a bit odd (`"\\\\"`) as a backslash has to be escaped twice when writing regular expression in a Java `String` literal.

If you want your operation to be platform independent, you may replace that line with

```
final String slash = Pattern.quote(FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator());
```

Of course, then, the input `path` must be in the right format for the platform as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex replace:

```
path = path.replaceAll(":.\\w+", "$0\\\\NEW_PATH");
```

Your code would be simpler if you used `/` instead of `\` for your path delimiters. eg, compare:

```
String path = "C:\\cresttest\\parent_3\\child_3_1\\child_3_1_.txt";
path = path.replaceAll(":.\\w+", "$0\\\\NEW_PATH");
```

with

```
String path = "C:/cresttest/parent_3.child_3_1/child_3_1_.txt";
path = path.replaceAll(":.\\w+", "$0/NEW_PATH");
```

Java can handle either delimiter on windows, but on linux only `/` works, so to make your code portable and more readable, prefer using `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, not sure whether this is what you wanted

```
public static String addFolderToPath(String originalPath, String newFolderName, int position){
    String returnString = "";
    String[] pathArray = originalPath.split("\\\\");

    for(int i = 0; i<pathArray.length; i++){
        returnString = returnString.concat(i==position ? "\\" + newFolderName : "");
        returnString = returnString.concat(i!=0 ? "\\" + pathArray[i] : "" + pathArray[i]);

    }
    return returnString;  
}
```

Call:

```
System.out.println(addFolderToPath("c:\\abc\\def\\ghi\\jkl", "test", 1));
System.out.println(addFolderToPath("c:\\abc\\def\\ghi\\jkl", "test", 2));
System.out.println(addFolderToPath("c:\\abc\\def\\ghi\\jkl", "test", 3));
System.out.println(addFolderToPath("c:\\abc\\def\\ghi\\jkl", "test", 4));
```

Run:

```
c:\test\abc\def\ghi\jkl
c:\abc\test\def\ghi\jkl
c:\abc\def\test\ghi\jkl
c:\abc\def\ghi\test\jkl
```